# Create Speech Bubble with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I am trying to create a speech bubble without using an image but unlike a typical speech bubble with a rectangle and a triangle, mine is a little more complex. See the following graphic:

[image: Speech Bubble]

I have looked at [this site](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/) and it seems that this may be possible with some cool CSS tricks but I do not really know where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is what I have so far:

```css
.speech {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.speech:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="speech"></div>
```

***Creating the initial circle is easy, and triangles arent too hard once you get the hang of them, the problem I have is that I need to curve the triangle in some way to match the graphic...***

This is not a duplicate as the end result must be transparent on all sides and can therefore be placed on top of anything else in the DOM and you wont be able to see where the triangle is cut...

Comment: parent div border radius 50% to give you a circle + child div as a triangle, pos absolute & off to the left. Go from there

Comment: The pointy but doesn't look much like a triangle to me... I'll post what I have so far

Comment: Why don't you just take the CSS from your example site of the bubble that looks the most like the one you want and work from there?

Comment: @Shomz I have had a play like that and have gone back and forth a lot... What I am really struggling with is curving the triangle underneath.

Comment: The triangles are done with `before` and `after` pseudo elements - one is used to create a square with a round border, and the other one cuts away the remaining square part of the previous one (by placing a background color on top of it).

Comment: @Shomz I will have another play

Comment: @JasCav Please see my edit to see why this is not a duplicate of said question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a circular pseudo-element, with a transparent background and border on only one side. Then use `transform` and `position: absolute` to manually set it in place.

You'll need to tweak the values depending on the desired size of the bubble and tail.

`z-index: -1` hides the pseudo-element under its parent.

```css
.bubble {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  background-color: grey;
}

.bubble::after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  
  bottom: -2px;
  left: -16px;
  
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom: 8px solid grey;
  
  transform: rotate(-55deg);
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bjj9x1tq) I created simple example with oval and triangle.

```css
.triangle-isosceles {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 1em 0 3em;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #000;
  background: #f3961c;
  border-radius: 50px / 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #f9d835, #f3961c);
}

/* creates triangle */
.triangle-isosceles:after {
  content: "";
  display: block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 0;
  border-width: 25px 8px 0 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f3961c transparent;
  -ms-transform: rotate(35deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(35deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-isosceles"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but what makes this particular question harder than a normal speech bubble with a triangle at the bottom is the fact that the triangle is curved...

Comment: @BenCarey ok, understood, working on it